# Android Tabs Views

Tags: java, android, xml, tabs, android-tabhost

I have decided to use views for my tab interface... 
I follow a tab interface tutorial and the result of this tutorial is 4 tabs without content (text) under my tabs..

I was wondering how views working.. how can I make a method to set content to tab from an another class.. So main.java is my main file with the views (tabs). Tab1.java has google maps navigate code.

How I can invoke the method setupTab and set the navigation function to tab 1.

Here you can see my code:
Thanks in advance!

```
 package CustomTabs;  
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabContentFactory;
    import android.widget.TabHost.TabSpec;

    public class CustomTabs extends Activity {

     private TabHost mTabHost;

     private void setupTabHost() {
      mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
      mTabHost.setup();
     }

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // construct the tabhost
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      setupTabHost();

      setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists));
      setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists));
      setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists));
      setupTab(new TextView(this), "Tab 4", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists));
      {
       final View v = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0);
       v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bg_selector));
       TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
       tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.tab_text_selector));
      }
      {
       final View v = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1);
       v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bg_selector));
       TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
       tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.tab_text_selector));
      }
      {
       final View v = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2);
       v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bg_selector));
       TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
       tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.tab_text_selector));
      }
      {
       final View v = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(3);
       v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_bg_selector));
       TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
       tv.setTextColor(this.getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.tab_text_selector));
      }

     }

     private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag, Drawable icon) {
      TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tag, icon).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
       public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
      });
      mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some Activity to do that. My sample took 2 Activity, first Activity will extends TabActivity and the second one will extends Activity.

Here is my simple sample :

- Activity that extends TabActivity

```
    package com.bsoft.activity;

    import android.app.TabActivity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TabHost;
    import com.bsoft.shared.Shared;

    public class ViewActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
              super.onCreate(bundle);

             String[] strVal = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("content").split(Shared.SPACE);
             setTitle(strVal[1]);

             Intent paliIntent = new Intent(this, PaliActivity.class);
             paliIntent.putExtra("val", strVal[2]);

             Intent indonesiaIntent = new Intent(this, IndonesiaActivity.class);
             indonesiaIntent.putExtra("val", strVal[3]);

            TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();     
            tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("Pali").setContent(paliIntent));  
           tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Indonesia").setContent(indonesiaIntent));         
        }
    }
```

- Another Activity :

```
    package com.bsoft.activity;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import com.bsoft.shared.Shared;

    public class IndonesiaActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
              super.onCreate(bundle);
              setContentView(R.layout.indonesia);

              String val = this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("val");       

              WebView indonesiaContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvIndoContent);
              indonesiaContent.loadData("" + val.replace("\n", "
") + "", Shared.MIME_TYPE, Shared.ENCODING);

              Shared s = new Shared();
             s.SetZoomControls(indonesiaContent, this);             
       }            
    }
```

Comment: No, you don't need Activities to do this.  He's using Views instead of Activities in his tabs.  You can do that.